# Step child if I am no longer married to the child's parent. How can it be?

Tags: legal-terms

I'm reading instructions to U.S. Diversity Immigrant Visa Program (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOQlh2d2EbQ&feature=youtu.be, http://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Diversity-Visa/DV-Instructions-Translations/DV-2016-Instructions-Translations/DV_2016_Instructions_English.pdf).

It states:

> Be sure to include:
>
> - all living natural children;
> - all living children legally adopted by you;
> - and, all living step-children who are unmarried and under the age of 21 on the date of your electronic entry, even if you are no longer legally married to the child’s parent, and even if the child does not currently reside with you and/or will not immigrate with you.

I can't get last list item: how can I have a step-child if I'm no longer legally married to that child’s parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fairly clear they mean for you to include persons you would consider *former* stepchildren but which they consider to be simply *stepchildren*. If you were married to a parent of children who weren't your offspring, they are calling these children your stepchildren and you should report them. Any further analysis is probably off-topic here but can be brought up on the English Language and Usage StackExchange.

Comment: Former stepchildren, right, now it makes sense. To make things clear: if I divorced and my wife (after divorce) born children from another partner, these children are NOT my former stepchildren, right?

Comment: @Tigrokonvel I am not a lawyer, but I don't think any reasonable person would consider these people your stepchildren. I mean, you might not even know that your ex-wife had other kids after you were divorced. On the other hand, you most likely do know about all your spouse's kids when you get married; they call you "stepfather" and you call them "stepchildren" for the duration of the marriage, at least. With children from a marriage after yours, they never call you "stepfather" and you never call them "stepchildren".

Comment: To clarify a point, you may still be legally considered a parent of a step-child after divorcing their biological parent. This is assuming that you legally adopted the step child when you married the biological parent, and that the legal adoption does not dissolve or otherwise become null during the divorce proceedings.